# SSRS Text Box in Page Header wrapping in PDF and should not

Tags: reporting-services, header, word-wrap

I have a simple matrix report with a count for the column/row.  I have a page header that appears fine in the display and in Excel but wraps when I export to PDF.  I tried Can Grow/shrink = No.  Tried expanding the Body width.  There is plenty of room.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the text box wider than it needed and it now formats correctly in PDF...